# how to return nodes indirectly related to each other

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have neo4j database contains a set of nodes and relationships, the nodes have property name and there are different types of relationships.

if i have a list of names ["A","C","E","Q","Z"], how I can find all the direct and indirect paths between those nodes? like if A connected to Z via one or more nodes which might be in the list and might not.

this cypher query returns only those nodes which are connected directly

```
MATCH (a)-[r]-(b) 
WHERE a.name IN ["A","C","E","Q","Z"] AND 
      b.name IN ["A","C","E","Q","Z"]  
RETURN a,b,r
```

and this query return unrelated nodes

```
MATCH (a)-[r*0..2]-(b) 
WHERE a.name IN ["A","C","E","Q","Z"] AND 
      b.name IN ["A","C","E","Q","Z"]  
RETURN a,b,r
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you mean:

```
MATCH (a)-[r*2]-(b) WHERE ...
             ^ note
```

`0..2` means *"zero, one or two relationships"*. If you include `0` you will get every node that matches the `WHERE` clauses and if you include `1` you get *"only those nodes which are connected directly"*.

Instead, the above matches *"exactly two"*, i.e. with a single other node in-between. For *"two or more"*, you could use `2..`.